# Adding a searchbox in my windows phone 7 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am building an application for Windows Phone 7 where i need to add a search box which should look like this:

[image]

Now on trying to type something here it should display the data that is present in the webservice. Suppose someone types the letter "A" it should display the data starting with A from the Web service. Please give me some idea on how to do this.

My xaml:

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="acBox" FilterMode="Custom" Width="344" Canvas.Left="53" Canvas.Top="6" Height="72">.
                <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="None" Margin="0,0,5,5"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
            </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
```

Cs file:

```
public City()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.acBox.ItemFilter = Search;
        LoadData();
    }

    bool Search(string search, object value)
    {
        //
    }
```

// here i want to search from the web service.

Comment: @aloisdg I am not getting any proper idea on how to proceed. So would be grateful if u can give some idea so that i can proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AutoCompleteBox from the [WindowsPhone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/). Nokia have a good [tutorial](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_use_Auto_Complete_Box_in_Windows_Phone) about it. Another one by [GeekChamp](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/data-binding-the-windows-phone-toolkit-autocompletebox).

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Width="450" Grid.Row="0"
                         Name="autoCompleteBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         ItemsSource="{StaticResource AutoCompletions}"/>
```

[image]

Comment: there is an error that "The resource AutoCompletions couldnot be resolved

Comment: @bhaku did you just copy/paste the snippet or did you follow one of the tutorial ?

Comment: If it's work, you can upvote and mark as resolve. :)

Comment: Sure....can u please see the code i added and tell me how do i make that search in the web service

Comment: @bhaku you will have to make a request to your service and fill you list with it, then you bind : `this.acBox.ItemsSource = dataSource;` as said in the tuto.